# Harry Potter for Adults

Tags: harry-potter

I have heard rumors that there is Adult versions of the Harry Potter book series that were only released in Europe. Not porn type adult but more graphic in nature. In this series supposedly Dumbledore is gay. Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 41):

Yes, but not in the way your question suggests. There were versions of the books released for adults in the UK that had much plainer covers; the idea being that adults would be less embarrassed about reading the Harry Potter books in public places (such as on public transport) if it wasn't quite so obvious *what* they were reading. I have no idea if this was limited to the UK, however, or if a similar thing happened in the rest of Europe, the US, and other countries.

[image: Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone] [image: Harry Potter and the Chanber of Secrets]

The content of the books, however, was identical to the versions of the books aimed at children. Dumbledore being gay is mentioned by JKR in [an interview](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more), but there's no references - graphic or otherwise - in any version of the books that have been released.

Comment: ... *trying to remember if that steamy scene was in HP books or fanfic*...

Comment: Hm... I just hid my HP books in Wall Street Journal when on subway...

Answer (score 4):

Like Anthony Grist said, there were no versions of the book with different content.

However, there were a number of fake/fan fiction versions of some of the novels. Yes, some people/groups actually wrote entire books. I read one of the fake versions of The Deathly Hallows that came out before the real version. It was an interesting read and contained some remarkable similarities to the real version - as well as some wild divergences, including "adult" content.

Comment: "The Seventh Horcrux", I assume? I admit to liking it more than JKR-written fanfic :)

Comment: No, it had the same title as the actual 7th book, just different content.